# Behavior of SqlLite rowid in case of a INTEGER primary key

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

If I have a non-integer primary-key the rowid is an auto-increment starting at 1.

```
sqlite> create table t1 (name text, documentid integer, primary key (name));
sqlite> insert into t1 (name, documentid) values ('max', 123);
sqlite> insert into t1 (name, documentid) values ('duf', 321);
sqlite> select rowid,* from t1;
1|max|123
2|duf|321
```

But if I have a INTEGER primary-key it seems the rowid is equal to it.

```
sqlite> create table t2 (name text, xid integer, primary key (xid));
sqlite> insert into t2 (name, xid) values ('max', 123);
sqlite> insert into t2 (name, xid) values ('duf', 321);
sqlite> select rowid,* from t2;
123|max|123
321|duf|321
```

Thats unexpected for me. I would expect rowid to behave like in the 1st sample.

Is that normal behaviour? Can I make it work like expected?

I am using SqlLite3 3.27

The problem is not the value as long it is uniqua (must be by definition of primary). But in JDBC I can not address ResultSet.getInt ("rowid") anymore - need to use getInt ("xid") instead" to make it work. Thats abnormal to a table with a non-integer primar-key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column is just an alias for the `rowid`. It acts the same (Having a value automatically assigned if left out when inserting a row), and doesn't even take up any extra space in the database. You can reference the column via its name, `rowid`, or any of the other standard aliases for `rowid` like `oid`.

From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid):

> With one exception noted below, if a rowid table has a primary key that consists of a single column and the declared type of that column is "INTEGER" in any mixture of upper and lower case, then the column becomes an alias for the rowid. Such a column is usually referred to as an "integer primary key". A PRIMARY KEY column only becomes an integer primary key if the declared type name is exactly "INTEGER". Other integer type names like "INT" or "BIGINT" or "SHORT INTEGER" or "UNSIGNED INTEGER" causes the primary key column to behave as an ordinary table column with integer affinity and a unique index, not as an alias for the rowid.

If you just do

```
INSERT INTO t2(name) VALUES ('max');
```

a value will be automatically generated for `xid` instead of explicitly using the one provided in the insert like in your example.

Comment: With JDBC I can not longer access rowid. Thats the problem.

Comment: @chris01 That's some JDBC-specific behavior then, because sqlite doesn't care. Just use the name you gave it instead of `rowid` in your queries.

Comment: Accessing it with the column-number instead of the column-name does work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's the normal behavior. 
When you define an integer column `xid` as `primary key`, then `xid` is just an alias of `rowid`.
What you can do is define `xid` as `UNIQUE` and not `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
create table t2 (name text, xid integer unique)
```

Then you will have the functionality that you want, because the `rowid` will be a different auto increment column.
Or define `xid` as `TEXT`:

```
create table t2 (name text, xid text, primary key (xid));
```

In this case also `rowid` is a different column and don't worry about the data you store in `xid`. 
You can treat this column just like an integer column so you can perform any arithmetic calculation and aggregation.
You can find more here: https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html